# spring-security: multiple auth providers for spring-mvc web application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like to extend an existing spring-security authentication mechanism.

The existing implementation is comprised of two `AuthenticationProvider`s:

- a standard `DaoAuthenticationProvider` (delegating to a `UserDetailsService`)
- a custom `AuthenticationProvider`

(each covering a different auth scenario)

I want to incorporate another condition of entry ("the 3rd provider"). User will then have to pass auth by either one of the above-providers, as-well as this new condition.

I understand `AuthenticationProvider`s as complementing each other. If the first fails, authentication is passed-down to the next provider. That's fine for the 2 existing providers, but doesn't work well with the 3rd provider.

If I place the 3rd provider as the last `<authentication-provider>`, it won't get invoked if the user has been authenticated by either one of the preceding providers. Place it as first, and even if it fails auth, the other providers still get called. The only way I see for preempting the provider chain is to throw an `AccountStatusException`. So how can an `AuthenticationProvider` tell next-in-line not to run?

Appreciate guidance. Thanks.

Using spring security 4.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the similar action that the two providers should both take. Can you describe that a little more? The reason is that it's not clear to me that a filter is what you want. It might be simpler than that.

Comment: @AlanHay: the solution described in the link will invoke the filter for every request, authenticated pages, resources, the lot. I'm seeking the same behavior as an authentication filter.

Comment: @jzheaux: the functionality I mean to implement is another condition of entry. It involves dipping into the db, checking some condition relating to the user (checking whether the user has some association), and return a 'go'/'no go' based on that. So a user has to pass both the password test AND this extra verification.

Comment: Thanks, @pointyhat. AuthenticationProviders make authentication decisions, so I wouldn't place an additional authentication decision into a filter. And providers aren't designed really to be collaborative, so it feels odd to me to say that one provider makes a decision that another provider could possibly override. Instead, I'd have each individual provider do the extra validation, so no custom filter. Since your question is about custom filters, I'll not post an answer, but feel free to adjust your question, if you'd like me to flesh out what I'm saying in the form of an example.

Comment: @jzheaux: adjusted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve it by implementing a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, which internally contains these 3 `AuthenticationProvider`. In this way , you are free to implement any logics to decide how to delegate the request to which `AuthenticationProvider` to process and the logic of the authentication sequences etc. according to your business rules.

Something like below:

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider{


     private DaoAuthenticationProvider existingDaoAuthenticationProvider;
     private AuthenticationProvider existingCustomAuthenticationProvider;
     private AuthenticationProvider newCustomAuthenticationProvider;


     public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{

         String checkingResult = checkDBForUserAuthentication(authentication);

         if(checkingResult == "foo"){
             existingDaoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
         }else if(checkingResult == "bar"){
             existingCustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
         }else{
            //Another checking satisfy.......
            newCustomAuthenticationProvider().authenticate(authentication);

         }
     }
}
```

And make sure you only register this `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: I don't see how the above solution can avoid re-implementing at least some of the logic in `ProviderManager` (handling exceptions, null auth response, conditions of delegation to next provider).

Comment: I am not suggesting you re-implement the logic of `ProviderManager` and actually you don't need. I just propose you control the logic which `AuthenticationProvider` should be delegated to  by always ensure that there is only one `AuthenticationProvider` registered to the `ProviderManager`